Custom credential provider check credentials before MFA
I am developing a custom credential provider and need to pre-check domain or local user credentials before a MFA operation against Active directory or cached credentials. I am now using LogonUser method to check. It works well in all my situations but i have a small problem, if there is Network available but DC is not available, LogonUser method takes very long time (~45 seconds). Does anyone have idea how can i pass this? Or should i change my validation method?

no way, because user logon data is stored on DC. and why LogonUser but not LsaLogonUser

Thanks for reply. What is the difference? Will LsaLogonUser wait shorter? What will be the difference?

of course no. simply format of data which you have in cred provider much more suitable for LsaLogonUser

it not change your result (in case password provider, but LsaLogonUser much more flexible). but it much more easy to use and can be used with any crededential data

I'll use it in my provider. Thanks.

There is one more thing, If i disconnect computer that provider installed from network, it checks cached credentials immediately. The only problem is computer connected to network, but dc down.

are if you use only built-in cred providers will be another result ? because anyway the LsaLogonUser will be called

If i use built-in cred-provider, it logons quickly.

so set bp in winlogon.AuthenticateUser and look which params passed to UMgrLogonUser or LsaLogonUser

really what you need - use WinLocalSid (S-1-2-0) (  in pTokenGroups (exist in LsaLogonUser and in LogonUserExExW )

I'm using this call: LogonUserExA(szUser, NULL, szPwd, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL); to check the users password.

I think i come up with a solution with help of Alexander's comment. I am using
LogonUser(userName, domain, password, (int)LogonTypes.Network, (int)LogonProviders.WinNT40, ref refToken)

Using LogonTypes.Network and LogonProvider.WinNT40 is faster then I used to try. It takes 12 seconds to authenticate user if DC is unavailable.
Here is my older code
LogonUser(userName, domain, password, (int)LogonTypes.Interactive, (int)LogonProviders.Default, ref refToken)

this was taking 45 seconds to authenticate user if DC unavailable.
